# Performance difference between h2o MOJO vs POJO when deploying

Tags: java, h2o

I have trained a binary classifier model using `h2o.GLM`. I have around 5-10 features. I am wondering which would be faster in production?

1. Coding the logistic regression in my java code.
2. Using the POJO by h2o.
3. Using the MOJO generated by h2o.

Will this answer change if I trained a Random Forest model instead of GLM?

I need to score ~100 million rows. I am already distributing scoring of different observations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For logistic regression either the POJO or MOJO will be fine.  Prefer the MOJO for better backwards-compatibility properties.

For Random Forest of depth more than about 6, definitely use the MOJO.  Really big (for example 1 GB of java code or more) RF models won't even compile.

MOJOs don't need to be compiled, which is very convenient, and for really deep trees they run faster and have very consistent run times.

Comment: Is there any tutorial on how to deploy a distributed h2o model in azure rest api?